# Abuse of match?

Tags: scala, coding-style

Would you consider the following block of code match abuse and if so what's a more elegant way to do it without a big if-else-if block?

```
def sum(base: Int, xs: List[Int]): Int = {
  base match {
    case 0 => 1
    case _ if (base < 0) => 0
    case _ if (xs.isEmpty) => 0
    case _ => xs.sum
  }
}
```

Comment: Very similar to my countChange implementation, but I used an inner function :)

Comment: You are aware of the honor code for Functional Programming Principles in Scala by Martin Odersky? "I will not make solutions to homework, quizzes or exams available to anyone else."

Comment: @som-snytt I'm not sure I'm following you, (I'm targeting Chris here). The code Chris presents is the answer that will give you full score by the grader in the course. Not the answers but the question code. The honor code is very explicit and you can't miss it if you are enrolled in the course. "I will not make solutions to homework, quizzes or exams available to anyone else. This includes both solutions written by me, as well as any official solutions provided by the course staff."

Comment: Apologies. I didn't realize that posting my solution without mention of the course would be a problem. The count change problem is common and implementations are readily available online in many languages, including Scala.  I will gladly redo the example to a more generic one but it would probably confuse anyone looking at dhg's answer.

Comment: Can I explain to folks here that SO mods don't police non-SE community terms, conditions, "honour codes", copyright violations etc. That's something Coursera would need to raise directly with SE.

Comment: Example has been edited to be generic (and in turn nonsensical).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, this an abuse of match.  You've basically just written a big if-else-if block, but in a more awkward form.  What's wrong with if-statements?

I think it's much cleaner to just write this:

```
def countChange(money: Int, coins: List[Int]): Int = {
  if(money == 0) 1
  else if (money < 0) 0
  else if (coins.isEmpty) 0
  else countChange(money, coins.tail) + countChange(money - coins.head, coins)
}
```

If you want to stick with a `match`, you can move more of the checking into the match itself, so that it's actually doing something:

```
def countChange(money: Int, coins: List[Int]): Int = {
  (money, coins) match {
    case (0, _) => 1
    case _ if (money < 0) => 0
    case (_, Nil) => 0
    case (_, coinsHead :: coinsTail) => countChange(money, coinsTail) + countChange(money - coinsHead, coins)
  }
}
```

Comment: Personally, I think the *match/case* version in the question is clearer and visually more pleasant than the succession of *if/else if*. Because of the `=>` it has more separation between the conditions and the result expressions. Also, I can immediately tell that `money match { ... }` will be one expression, where as it is harder to say where the *if* expression ends.

Comment: IMO the _if/else_ is more readable, but if I were going to use the `match` I think I'd try to abbreviate. I'd write the second case as `case (m, _) if (m < 0) => 0` and the last case as `case (m, h :: t) => countChange(m, t) + countChange(m - h, coins)`.

Comment: Note that you have posted a solution to a graded assignment in Functional Programming Principles in Scala by Martin Odersky? I understand that you don't have to care as you aren't enrolled but it would be good to delete your answer as it implicit encourages cheating by making it searchable in engines.

Answer (score 2):

No. Why abuse? It's fairly readable IMO...

The problem I see is that `money match ...` is fairly arbitrary (you only use the direct pattern in the first case); a complete "abuse" would start like

```
() match {
  case _ if (money == 0) => 1
  ...
```

So perhaps stick to if-else; you can combine the second and third condition (`if( money < 0 || coins.isEmpty ) ...`)

---

Also note that although you "know" in the end that coins is not empty and thus may "safely" call `head` and `tail` on it, this is a typical source of unexpected runtime errors. The advantage of `coins match { case Nil => ...; case head :: tail => ...}` is that you cannot make such a mistake.