# What is encouraged style in comparing two numbers in Scala?

Tags: scala

When compare two numbers, we can use if-else or pattern matching:

If-else

```
if (guess < secretNum) println("Too small!\n")
else if (guess > secretNum) println("Too big!\n")
else {
  println("You win!\n")
  continueLooping = false
  }
```

Pattern matching

```
guess match {
  case x if x < secretNum => println("Too small!\n")
  case x if x > secretNum => println("Too big!\n")
  case _ => {
    println("You win!\n")
    continueLooping = false
    }
}
```

Are there any clearer way to write this? and which is encouraged?

**Edit**

Here is the Rust way:

```
    match guess.cmp(&secret_number) {
        Ordering::Less => println!("Too small!"),
        Ordering::Greater => println!("Too big!"),
        Ordering::Equal => { println!("You win!"); break;
        }
```

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556236/abuse-of-match and with a better answer by @dhg

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to the Scalaz library you can match `Rust` for style and clarity:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

guess ?|? secretNum 
  match {
    case Ordering.LT => println("Too small!")
    case Ordering.GT => println("Too big!")
    case Ordering.EQ => println("You win!")
}
```

In terms of preference, it depends. If performance is critical then the `if-else` beats the pattern matching idiom. If readability is paramount, then pattern matching with the facilities Scalaz provides leads to more readable code in my opinion; It avoids the use of equational guards as you did in your example.

Answer (score 2):

The if-else way.  The pattern matching seems weird since you're not actually trying to match any patterns, so you end up just having more syntactic noise.

Answer (score 0):

Consider method `signum` available in `Double`, `Float`, `Long` and `Int` classes, which maps the sign of the numerical value onto `-1` (for negative), `0` (for zero) or `1` (for positive),

```
(gess - secretNum).signum match {
  case -1 => "Too small"
  case 1  => "Too big"
  case _  => "You win"
}
```